# Send mail with chart

Tags: php, email, charts, pie-chart

I'm wanting to send email with charts in the email body in php, but I'm not getting.

I have tested some ways, for example image charts google (deprecated), google charts, jqgraph but without success.

Answer (score 5):

One solution would be to create a static image generated on the server and to send that image in your email. The javascript charting library [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) provides a special build to work with the headless server-side browser PhantomJS, allowing you to create png images of the charts. http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/phantomjs/

I'm a part of the ZingChart development team, so let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably to use a static image chart generator.  There are a number of different services available online.  For this purpose I created [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io), an open-source rendering service for Chart.js charts.

Since you tagged your post `pie-chart`, let's make a Chart.js pie chart config (see [Chart.js pie chart reference](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html)):

```
{
  "type": "pie",
  "data": {
    "datasets": [
      {
        "data": [84, 28] 
      } 
    ],
    "labels": ["Data1", "Data2"] 
  } 
}
```

You can put this config into a PHP variable:

```php
$chartConfig = '{
  "type": "pie",
  "data": {
    "datasets": [
      {
        "data": [84, 28] 
      } 
    ],
    "labels": ["Data1", "Data2"] 
  } 
}';
```

URL encode it for the `https://quickchart.io/chart` endpoint:

```php
$chartUrl = 'https://quickchart.io/chart?c=' . urlencode($chartConfig);
```

Then, embed this URL directly in an email using a standard HTML `<img>` tag:

```
$email_body = "Please see my chart: <img src=\"$chartUrl\" />";
```

It displays the image below!

[image: Pie chart image for email]

Alternative approaches include:

- [wkhtmltoimage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org), a command-line utility for rendering pages
- Headless renderers like [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) (PhantomJS is ok too, but it's no longer supported)
- Self-host your own [QuickChart](https://github.com/typpo/quickchart) instance